# Azure CosmosDB get consumed througput programatically

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have failed to found how to get amount of consumed RU's from CosmosDB API.

Azure Portal has a handy graph for it so there should be a way how to get this dataset.

Graph from Azure Portal: 
[image]

Answer (score -3):

With .NET SDK for Cosmos DB, you can use the [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents#response) Header: x-ms-request-charge (The number of request units consumed by the operation)

Comment: That is not why I am looking for. I would have to track & store every operation made to collection. 

Graph above is directly from Azure portal monitoring and is showing aggregated value per collection and partition.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer so as to be more clear on what you are looking for? Which Cosmos DB Service API are you using? Are you seeking graphical data via the Portal or are you looking to read this data from a client? Thank you!

Comment: I am using cosmosdb/documentDB. I need to monitor consumed throughput per partition in order to be able to autoscale. I have found above chart in the portal showing the data I need, but I am not able to find them in any API. I have tried CosmosDB node client and azure-arm-cosmosdb node library.